# Can all continuous functions on a compact set be approximated by 1-lipschitz functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lipschitz-functions, riemann-integration

As an exercise in my book, there are a few questions that should guide us through the fact that if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is Riemann integrable on a compact interval, then $f(g)$ is also Riemann integrable.

1. Show that if $ f$ is 1-Lipschitz then $f(g)$ is Riemann integrable.

> 2. Show that every continuous function can be written as a uniform limit of 1-Lipschitz (!) functions.

3. Deduce that if $f$ is continuous then $f(g)$ is Riemann integrable.

Did the author maybe mean "uniform limit of Lipschitz functions"? Because if I am not mistaken, $\sqrt x$ cannot be represented as uniform limit of 1-Lipschitz functions on any compact neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: It is really hard to say what *did* the author mean. Clearly a uniform limit of $1$-Lipschitz functions is $1$-Lipschitz, but not every continuous function is $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=\min(n\,x,\sqrt x)$ on $[0,1]$. Then $f_n$ is Lipschitz and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$. However the $f_n$ are not uniformly Lipschitz, that is, the Lipschitz constant depends on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters said, it is impossible to approximate a general continuous function by $1$-Lipschitz functions, since the $1$-Lipschitz property passes to limits (even pointwise ones).

However, on a compact metric space $X$, it is possible to approximate a continuous function $f$ uniformly by Lipschitz functions $f_n$ with Lipschitz constant depending on $n$. This is enough for the above proof.

Such an approximation can be defined in one line:
$$f_n(x) = \sup_{y\in X} (f(y)-nd(x,y)).$$
This is evidently $n$-Lipschitz, and $f_n\ge f$. When $n>2\delta^{-1}\sup_X|f|$, the supremum is in effect taken over $d(x,y)\le \delta$, which yields $f_n\to f$ uniformly.